# Simulating a LiIon battery in a laptop

Tags: lithium-ion, charger

A few years back I bought a NuVision Traveler 14" Laptop for $135. It's a total piece of crap but I use it for ssh so it doesn't matter. I hadn't used it for a bit and had left it plugged in. When I came back to it a few weeks ago it's battery looked like a pillow (inflated). I took it apart and removed the battery, I can replace the battery, but honestly I don't really need the battery and the battery would be half the price of the laptop.

Unfortunately when I remove the battery and I plug it in, it won't boot and it clicks (like sounds almost like a spark gap click) at about 4Hz (That's also the rate at which the SSD LED lights). My guess is the charge chip expects a battery to be there and when it dosn't get any load it freaks out and dies. My question is, is there any way to "simulate" the battery so the charge controller dosn't freak out and I can use the laptop as a keyboard and screen without battery.

Best I can tell the PMIC is bd2670 but that doesn't seem to include a charge controller. Battery controller is probably a [bq715](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24715.pdf?ts=1626727146466&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

[image: connector]
[image: battery stats]
[image: battery pillow goodness]

Comment: Which charge controller?  Knowing what that chip expects is likely the answer.  Try to get a datasheet for it then edit your question with a link to it.

Comment: @rdtsc it looks like it might be a bq715 https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24715.pdf?ts=1626727146466&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Answer (score 1):

> My guess is the charge chip expects a battery to be there and when it
> dosn't get any load it freaks out and dies.

You may be right, in which case the laptop may require the battery to handle surge currents during operation.

> My question is, is there any way to "simulate" the battery so the
> charge controller dosn't freak out and I can use the laptop as a
> keyboard and screen without battery.

You could try using a power supply set to just below 8.7V (so the charger doesn't try to charge it). It will need to be rated for the peak current drain of the laptop, which is an unknown quantity but probably several amps.

Another possibility is an array of super-capacitors in parallel and series to provide the voltage rating and peak current required. This may cost more than a battery.

But the best way to 'simulate' a battery is with... another battery! If you can't afford ~$35 then see if you can find a second-hand battery with similar specs (most importantly a maximum voltage of 8.7 V). Try your local laptop repair shop or e-waste center. It can be an old, tired battery with lower capacity, so long as it can handle the charging current and deliver enough current to run your laptop for a few seconds.

You might even be able to use a 6 cell NiMH or Nicad battery (which is ~8.7 V fully charged).

Comment: So it would be a terrible idea to put  like 1k resistors in series and the middle terminal to the sense circuit?

Comment: You could try it, but I doubt it would do any good by itself. The charger expects to see voltage coming from the battery, and should not try to charge or use it otherwise. If the power supply was designed to bypass a battery with no usable capacity it should work without it.

Comment: the resistor trick works on many older android phones.

Comment: If the middle contact just goes to a thermistor it may work (if you match the resistance). It all depends on how 'smart' the battery management is. Since this battery is screwed in and not normally removable, any lack of voltage or temperature sensor might be considered a fault. If the pin is used to communicate with a BMS inside the battery then the only options might to repack or replace the battery.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I always assumed that the middle terminal went to the middle of the two (i'm assuming) cells for charge balancing

Comment: You may be right. I can't find any info on 2 cell laptop battery pinouts. I have a 2 cell Li-ion battery with 3 terminals that are marked P+, P-, and TH (connected to a thermistor inside) but it is not a laptop battery.